# Set message box from Message.Show() as a child of Wix installer window

Tags: dialog, wix, custom-action

In my custom actions, I've used **MessageBox.Show()** to show a dialog whether needed. For ex: during database installation, I'd like to show a message to user if any error. But the message box is not set as a child of Wix window by default, thus the end-user can leave the message box and touch the Back, Next button ...

Is there any way to set the message box as a child of the main Wix installer window?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bad ways and good ways. The bad ways involve FindWindow calls so you can parent appropriately. The good ways involve calls to [MsiProcessMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370354%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), Session.Message, or whatever wrapper is available. However if this custom action is being invoked from a [DoAction ControlEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the latter will not work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good ways. The **session.Message** in custom actions works very well.